# Is it possible to remove touch screen requirement from UWP app?

Tags: uwp, windows-store, windows-dev-center

I published a Windows 10 app in Store, and I am using the default appxmanifest file. Problem is - on the app store page Touch is listed in System Requirements/Minimum, which can mislead users (especially on desktops): the app does not require touch, you can do everything with mouse.

How do I (if possible), specify, that Touch is not required?

Answer (score 4):

> How do I (if possible), specify, that Touch is not required?

When you create your new submission in Dev Center, you could uncheck the `Minimum hardware` for `TouchScreen` feature under `System Requirements` in **Property** and you could check `Mouse` if you want customer to know it's needed:
[image]

After your new submission passes certification, your Store listing will be changed so that customers on devices without a touch screen will not see a warning if they try to download your app.